# How to build Openssl TLS V1.2 for Windows XP?

Tags: openssl, windows-xp, tls1.2, windows-xp-sp3

I have used precompiled libraries of OpenSSL TLS v1.2 for windows 7. Now I want to build OpenSSL with TLS v1.2 support for Windows XP. I googled on the net but found out that Windows XP does not have support for TLS v1.2 and only supports till SSLv3, but I have a requirement to build OpenSSL TLSv1.2 for Windows XP. How can I build OpenSSL with TLSv1.2 for Windows XP or is there any workaround which I can use to make TLS v1.2 work for Windows XP.

Comment: As far as I know, the process to build on Windows is the same for all versions of Windows. Just use the regular Windows build procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jww, building from sources is essentially the same regardless of the version of Windows you work on.

That said, You may be able to get the pre-compiled libraries you need from one of the links here:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Or you can learn what you need from here:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `--disable-schannel` `--no-async` configure switches.

[Source](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/issues/219)